# UPU S-10 standard, regular expression for capturing the tracking code from postal companies

Tags: regex

What's the regular expression that can capture tracking code from postal companies belonging to UPU based on the S-10 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPU (Universal Postal Union), and its members uses a tracking code which consists of 3 parts. The first part is Two letters, the first one of them represents the service that is being used. The only acceptable letters are

```
«A» - Mail is not insured (less than 2 kg)
«R» - Registered Mail (less than 2 kg)
«V» - Registered Mail (Insured）(less than 2 kg)
«C» - Ordinary Parcel (more than 2 kg)
«L» - Airmail E-packet (less than 2 kg)
«E» - Express Mail Service (EMS more than 2 kg)
```

the second letter can be anything from the Latin alphabet. The second part is 9 digits with the last one being the check digit of their algorithm. The third and last part is two letters that correspond to the country based on [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1).

I was searching high and low to create a regex that will capture this particular string of characters. I making this post for anyone may looking out for it.

```
/(?:^[aArRvVcClLeE][a-zA-Z]\d{9}(A(D|E|F|G|I|L|M|N|O|R|S|T|Q|U|W|X|Z)|B(A|B|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|L|M|N|O|R|S|T|V|W|Y|Z)|C(A|C|D|F|G|H|I|K|L|M|N|O|R|U|V|X|Y|Z)|D(E|J|K|M|O|Z)|E(C|E|G|H|R|S|T)|F(I|J|K|M|O|R)|G(A|B|D|E|F|G|H|I|L|M|N|P|Q|R|S|T|U|W|Y)|H(K|M|N|R|T|U)|I(D|E|Q|L|M|N|O|R|S|T)|J(E|M|O|P)|K(E|G|H|I|M|N|P|R|W|Y|Z)|L(A|B|C|I|K|R|S|T|U|V|Y)|M(A|C|D|E|F|G|H|K|L|M|N|O|Q|P|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z)|N(A|C|E|F|G|I|L|O|P|R|U|Z)|OM|P(A|E|F|G|H|K|L|M|N|R|S|T|W|Y)|QA|R(E|O|S|U|W)|S(A|B|C|D|E|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|R|T|V|Y|Z)|T(C|D|F|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|O|R|T|V|W|Z)|U(A|G|M|S|Y|Z)|V(A|C|E|G|I|N|U)|W(F|S)|Y(E|T)|Z(A|M|W)))$/s
```

More about the S-10 standard can be found [here](http://pls.upu.int/document/2011/an/cep_c_4_gn_ep_4-1/src/d008_ad00_an01_p00_r00.pdf).